# Regex fomat phone (+00) 000 000 00 00 | (+00) 000-000-00-00 ​

Tags: regex, ruby, regex-group

Hello i want found a regular expression that accomplish this two formats:

(+00) 000 000 00 00

(+00) 000-000-00-00 ​

i am try this `(?:\+\s*\d{2}[\s-]*)?(?:\d[-\s]*){10}/` but its no working how i wanted, can you help me? i am using ruby i am probing this regex with https://rubular.com/.

Comment: `/\A\(\+\d{2}\) \d{3}([ -])\d{3}\1\d{2}\1\d{2}\z/`? https://rubular.com/r/bRvOkb3sMEtGyE

Comment: If you would prefer to not back-reference a capture group you could use `/\A\(\+\d{2}\) \d{3}(?: \d{3}(?: \d{2}){2}|-\d{3}(?:-\d{2}){2})\z/`. [Ref](https://rubular.com/r/dzkbWUkynEN5EK).

Comment: What will be the use of this regexp ? Scanning a file ? If it's input validation then you should just strip whatever's not a digit from the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```rb
/\A\(\+\d{2}\) \d{3}([ -])\d{3}\1\d{2}\1\d{2}\z/
/\A\(\+\d{2}\)\s\d{3}([\s-])\d{3}\1\d{2}\1\d{2}\z/
```

See the [Rubular demo](https://rubular.com/r/bRvOkb3sMEtGyE). Note that `\s` matches spaces, tabs, line breaks, any whitespace.

*More details*

- `\A` - start of string
- `\(\+` - `(+` substring
- `\d{2}` - two digits
- `\)` - a `)` char
- `\s` - a whitespace
- `\d{3}` - three digits
- `([\s-])` - Group 1: a whitespace or a `-` char
- `\d{3}` - three digits
- `\1` - backreference to Group 1: same value as in Group 1
- `\d{2}` - two digits
- `\1` - backreference to Group 1: same value as in Group 1
- `\d{2}` - two digits
- `\z` - end of string.